# Which state income tax will be applied on working as a traveling employee?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax

I live in State A where I have my home address. My work location is in State B. I also do work from home. When I travel, I stay in hotel.

Will my state tax fall in State A or State B? Can travel/hotel expenses can be deducted in the year end filing?

Comment: Can you add the states involved. There are different regulations that each state follow.

Comment: Possible (unanswered) duplicate: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/99096/36669

Comment: Does your employer pay for any of the hotel or transportation when you are working out of state?

Comment: No, I will have to pay by myself.

Comment: Needs a bit of clarification about what you mean by "travelling employee".  When you say "work location", is that where you actually work, or do you travel to different job sites?  As I did working construction jobs: in any year I might work jobs in half a dozen states.  But IIRC I paid non-resident taxes to the state where the company headquarters was (even though I never did any work in that state), and would have paid resident taxes to my home state, except that it doesn't have income tax.

Comment: I wasn’t aware of non resident tax & resident tax .. thanks for that details